# Print footnote outside of box

Tags: beamer, footnotes, tcolorbox

The footnote is printed inside the box. I want it to be below the box. See my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\useinnertheme{rounded}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows.meta, calc, positioning}
\tikzset{myarrow/.style={-Latex, rounded corners},}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    colback=bg, 
    colframe=blue!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=blue!75!black, 
    colbacktitle=bg,
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-1.2mm, xshift=2mm},
  title=#2,
  #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Parameterization of Graph Isomorphism Problem}

\begin{mybox}[colframe=green!75!black,coltitle=green!75!black, ]{GI parameterized by degree}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Given : $G$ and $H$, a parameter $d$ ( maximum degree ) \\~\\
    \item Decide : Is $G \cong H$?\\~\\
    \item $n^{O(d)}$ running time\footnote{This result is taken from paper titled " lsomorphism of Graphs of Bounded Valence Can Be Tested in Polynomial Time" by E M Luks} algorithm by E.M Luks
\end{itemize}
\end{mybox}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

See the compiled output:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not directly possible to use `\footnote` to be placed outside of the box, but using `\footnotemark` and `after=\footnotetext{...}` will work, but it is far from being convenient.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\useinnertheme{rounded}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows.meta, calc, positioning}
\tikzset{myarrow/.style={-Latex, rounded corners},}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    colback=bg, 
    colframe=blue!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=blue!75!black, 
    colbacktitle=bg,
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-1.2mm, xshift=2mm},
  title=#2,
  #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Parameterization of Graph Isomorphism Problem}

\begin{mybox}[colframe=green!75!black,coltitle=green!75!black,after={\refstepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{This result is taken from paper titled " lsomorphism of Graphs of Bounded Valence Can Be Tested in Polynomial Time" by E M Luks}}]

\begin{itemize}
    \item Given : $G$ and $H$, a parameter $d$ ( maximum degree ) \\~\\
    \item Decide : Is $G \cong H$?\\~\\
    \item $n^{O(d)}$ running time\footnotemark[\the\numexpr\value{footnote}+1] algorithm by E.M Luks
\end{itemize}
\end{mybox}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answers are beautiful +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\footnote[frame]{...}` to place the footnote at the bottom of the frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\useinnertheme{rounded}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows.meta, calc, positioning}
\tikzset{myarrow/.style={-Latex, rounded corners},}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    colback=bg, 
    colframe=blue!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=blue!75!black, 
    colbacktitle=bg,
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-1.2mm, xshift=2mm},
  title=#2,
  #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Parameterization of Graph Isomorphism Problem}

\begin{mybox}[colframe=green!75!black,coltitle=green!75!black, ]{GI parameterized by degree}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Given : $G$ and $H$, a parameter $d$ ( maximum degree ) \\~\\
    \item Decide : Is $G \cong H$?\\~\\
    \item $n^{O(d)}$ running time\footnote[frame]{This result is taken from paper titled " lsomorphism of Graphs of Bounded Valence Can Be Tested in Polynomial Time" by E M Luks} algorithm by E.M Luks
\end{itemize}
\end{mybox}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]