# Using footmisc package in tcolorbox environment

Tags: tcolorbox, footmisc

I am trying to create a footnote symbol * in a `tcolorbox` environment and the result is not the symbol nor at the bottom of the page instead within the box!

```
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!20!white,colframe=green!40!gray]
\color{green!40!gray}{\large {\bf Definitions}}\color{black} \ \ \ {\bf 
Strategy 
for Sketching Graphs}\footnote[1]{This strategy is refined further, for 
rational 
functions, in Section 2.3.}

\begin{enumerate}
\item[{\bf a)}]
\item[{\bf b)}]
\item[{\bf c)}]
\item[{\bf d)}]
\item[{\bf e)}]
\item[{\bf f)}]
\end{enumerate}

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

First of all `tcolorbox` is not reading the correct symbol for '1' in the `footmisc` package nor is the footnote at the bottom of the page. Please advise!

Comment: `tcolorbox` does not claim that footnotes appear at the bottom of the page. It's the same issue you would have with footnotes in `tabular` environment. Besides that, your document is not compilable

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but please note that the `\it`, `\bf`, etc. font macros are deprecated because
they do not use the new font selection scheme introduced with LaTeX2e.
Please use `{\itshape ..}`, `{\bfseries ..}` or `\textit{..}`, `\textbf{..}` instead.
See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516)
and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361)
for more information.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412716/print-footnote-outside-of-box and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376682/arabic-footnotes-in-tcolorbox

Comment: `tcolorbox` uses `mpfootnote` actually, that's why it does use the correct symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` macros:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!20!white,colframe=green!40!gray]
    \textcolor{green!40!gray}{\large \textbf{Definitions}}
    \quad\textbf{Strategy for Sketching Graphs}\footnotemark[1]

    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*)}]
        \item
        \item
        \item
        \item
        \item
        \item
    \end{enumerate}

\end{tcolorbox}
\footnotetext[1]{This strategy is refined further, for 
    rational functions, in Section 2.3.}
\end{document}
```

[image]